# get css value on media query change via enquire.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, window-resize, enquire.js

```
enquire

  .register('screen and (min-width: 1200px)', {

    match: function() {

      active_li_margin_left = $('li.active').css('margin-left')
      active_li_width = $('li.active').width()

      console.log(active_li_margin_left, active_li_width)

      zwarovsky();

    }

  })

  .register('screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px)', {

    match: function() {

      active_li_margin_left = $('li.active').css('margin-left')
      active_li_width = $('li.active').width()

      console.log(active_li_margin_left, active_li_width)

      zwarovsky();

    }

  })
```

li.active width change from 770px to 620px, where margin-left from -30px to -20px, this are bootstrap span8 items.

the problem:
seems that enquire fire the functions just before the css media query, so it pickup the previous values when you resize the window.

when i switch from 1200 to 980 resizing the browser window console log show 30px 770 instead 20px 660, and than when i switch back from 980 to 1200 console log show 20px 620.

Comment: It's very hard to understand the exact nature of the problem without a working example. Could you create a JSFiddle which demonstrates the issue? I'd be glad to have a look into it then